Can Visual Studio auto-populate new branch name in 'Create a new branch' dialog?
I frequently use the current branch name as a basis for a feature branch. This typically means retyping the current branch name and then adding more descriptors to the end.
For example, here I'd like to create a new branch based off develop called something like develop-task1234-adds-multithreading.

Having to retype the word 'develop' isn't so bad, but often the branch names are longer.
Is there a way to have the dialog auto-suggest/auto-fill with the current branch name? I'm currently using VS 2019.
